# I have configured vhost in apache,but it always go to default path?

Tags: linux, apache, apache2

I have configured in apache conf/httpd.conf

It like this

[image]

And in my vhost.d Directory,I have configured some host like this

[image]

and then in my windows computer ,I have configure the driver host to bind the two Domains(test.hr.oa.com,demo.oa.com) to my server ip,but it's no working ,
When I visit the url ,it's always go to the /var/www/html ?
I have restart my apache ,it's no working ,and in httpd.conf file,there is no configure about "/var/www/html"  ,but the all domains  go to /var/www/html

Finally: I found two httpd.conf  config files in my server. It like this
[image]

Previously，the apache have in my server,so I have tried

```
apachectrl restart
```

and

```
service httpd restart
```

they are both no working ,the Server tiped me that I should install httpd,
So I

```
yum install httpd
```

then the second httpd.conf file was added to my server.and Configuring the second config file is working.

So I want to know what's the relationship about apache and httpd?

Comment: What Linux distribution are you on?

Comment: I found two  httpd.conf  config files in   apache/conf  and httpd/conf ,the second is working

Comment: Then add what you found as a solution for people who would face the same problem.